# Parsing incoming e-mail header: Sender address invisible. Ascii / Unicode discrepancy?

Tags: python, email

Weird problem here.

I'm parsing incoming e-mails without problems 99% of the time with Python. A new issue arose recently where my script couldn't figure out what the incoming e-mail address was when sent from certain clients, like the built in e-mail client on the iPhone. My debug scripts would list the ["From"] key as the name without the e-mail address.

What I expect:

```
Ryan Martin <ryan@grouped.com>
```

What I'm seeing in my logs (and what my script is attempting to process):

```
Ryan Martin
```

But, if I text the log to my phone, I see it properly listed as

```
Ryan Martin <ryan@grouped.com>
```

So my first thought is that the e-mail address is encoded in something I'm not detecting properly. I know the information is there because I can see it on my phone. The Python script thinks it's blank and when saved to logs it's blank.

I'm parsing the e-mail and testing with this code:

```
parser = HeaderParser()
msg = parser.parsestr(self.message_as_string)
print msg["From"]
```

I assume the sender name is ascii and the actual bracketed e-mail address is encoded in something else, but I'm not sure.

So my question is:

> **How can I determine how the sender ("From") is encoding and how can I convert it into something I can use?**

As always, thank you.

Here is an example of the header:

```
['Received: (qmail 16170 invoked by uid 110); 14 Jun 2012 10:49:02 -0700\n', 'Delivered-To: 1-etest@grouped.com\n', 'Received: (qmail 16167 invoked from network); 14 Jun 2012 10:49:02 -0700\n', 'Received: from mail-pz0-f46.google.com (209.85.210.46)\n', '  by grouped.com with (RC4-MD5 encrypted) SMTP; 14 Jun 2012 10:49:02 -0700\n', 'Received: by dady13 with SMTP id y13so2807279dad.5\n', '        for <etest@grouped.com>; Thu, 14 Jun 2012 10:49:01 -0700 (PDT)\n', 'DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;\n', '        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;\n', '        h=subject:references:from:content-type:x-mailer:in-reply-to\n', '         :message-id:date:to:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version;\n', '        bh=8ta00o/UsoBbe+qrLFMT/1rE1AHRZyQSK1Az6Ve7ffE=;\n', '        b=A4aSj5duxG4nWr1+Dn/X614kOMJWq+nYo6jo7ntsXNCZquoxPW/+1FBVXs96Qi73cR\n', '         jW5sIO33mCe1fsRQvDn+9Mp/i9kSNwzGX/+QwseBGy78bNf2ZDxDhbJZ7nKm9qlsvc2x\n', '         j9m/j8mZG7/j3ruz1b9O+j1KwCqzzl9Lgqj
 Lx0af7/MCEHVfE4rIpJsOBOzUJR8EA8MJ\n', '         5LvtdKxS3/8cqKX92plziGOWMiRjI+euBE3apHou7PUM9/BpHD4o2LH1OjSQKo6sVNmt\n', '         8CiB5vw3UvNDU+nMgjWcvirJsE8xzXDqkulbDiyI5Ba5QagfpwAKUb/OQpDlkY4gK+Bv\n', '         fTsg==\n', 'Received: by 10.68.225.6 with SMTP id rg6mr10617173pbc.100.1339696141712;\n', '        Thu, 14 Jun 2012 10:49:01 -0700 (PDT)\n', 'Return-Path: <some_sender@gmail.com>\n', 'Received: from [10.230.186.251] (125.sub-174-254-212.myvzw.com. [174.254.212.125])\n', '        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ol1sm10204626pbb.25.2012.06.14.10.48.53\n', '        (version=SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);\n', '        Thu, 14 Jun 2012 10:49:00 -0700 (PDT)\n', 'Subject: Re: Prempus Patterson replied to a post on etest\n', 'References: <20120614173822.12044.qmail@grouped.com>\n', 'From: Ryan Martin <some_sender@gmail.com>\n', 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n', '\tboundary=Apple-Mail-17F5BF62-A532-49C2-BF72-499A1EEB510E\n', 'X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (10A5316k)\n', 'In-Reply-To: <
 20120614173822.12044.qmail@grouped.com>\n', 'Message-Id: <8321D4D0-E41A-4A1C-87DC-D7A2E462AC6A@gmail.com>\n', 'Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 10:48:48 -0700\n', 'To: Prempus Patterson <etest@grouped.com>\n', 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n', 'Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)\n', '\n', '\n', '--Apple-Mail-17F5BF62-A532-49C2-BF72-499A1EEB510E\n']
```

Comment: Are you viewing your logs in a browser?

Comment: This does not _smell_ like an encoding problem.

Comment: In a browser, in a text editor, in Thunderbird. The e-mail address is always invisible, unless I literally text it to my phone. Then I can see the e-mail address. Python also doesn't know what to do with it. The script just thinks there isn't an e-mail address.

Comment: It would be most useful if you past the actual string headers that poses the problem...

Comment: Updated to include the header. The header looks fine though and I'm sure it's re-encoded by posting to stack.

Comment: I did `r = [ <your-stuff> ]` and then `parser.parsestr(''.join(r))['From']` and returns the full line all right: `'Ryan Martin <some_sender@gmail.com>'`

Comment: Rodrigo - Thanks, but that's essentially what I'm already doing and it isn't working. Pointing out that it works for you isn't helpful in solving my problem. I, too, can see the proper result in some places. But there is clearly something else wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i'm not sure exactly what was causing my problem, but I did find a solution that works for now. Brace yourselves, it's a bit ugly:

```
    # At this point, we know there is a < bracket in the 'From' value
    acceptable_chars = ["a", "b", "c", ... "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "_", ".", "@"]
    from_str = msg["From"].lower().split("<")[-1]

    stripped_from = ''
    for letter in from_str:
        if letter in acceptable_chars:
            stripped_from += letter

    return stripped_from
```

I don't know why or how the script is able to understand the encoded information this way, but not when evaluation the string as a whole. I imagine it's because of a hidden unicode character after the name but before the first bracket.

Either way, it's working, but I'm open to rewrites or other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to save the *raw* (off the wire) message to a file, and open it in a hex editor.

Or, more directly, capture the incoming message in wireshark and look at the bytes in the `From:` line. Then you'll see if there's some weird character in the header that is messing up the parser.